# How can I substitute a left join in SQL

Tags: sql, left-join

Can anyone tell me how can I write the equivalent of a left join without really using left joins.

```
Select * from a left join b on a.name = b.name.
```

Comment: Select * from b right join a on a.name = b.name.

Comment: Just kidding, why would you want to?

Comment: I really meant without using joins at all, the problem is I cannot get left join to work in Hibernate and was going to completely eliminate it

Comment: I would be *remarkably* surprised if Hibernate was incapable of generating queries that include left joins. Maybe you should ask a question about that instead? (Whatever answers you do get here, I'd be surprised if you could force Hibernate to generate them)

Answer (score 11):

Bear in mind that SQL’s outer join is a kind of relational union which is expressly designed to project null values. If you want to avoid using the null value (a good thing, in my opinion), you should avoid using outer joins. Note that modern relational languages have dispensed with the concept of null and outer join entirely.

This outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.id, T1.value, T2.other_value
  FROM T1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
          ON T1.id = T2.id;
```

…is semantically equivalent to this SQL code:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.value, T2.other_value
  FROM T1
       INNER JOIN T2
          ON T1.id = T2.id
UNION
SELECT T1.id, T1.value, NULL
  FROM T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM T2
                    WHERE T1.id = T2.id
                  );
```

The second query may look long winded but that’s only because of the way SQL has been designed/evolved. The above is merely a natural join, a union and a semijoin. However, SQL has no semijoin operator, requires you to specify column lists in the `SELECT` clause and to write `JOIN` clauses if your product hasn’t implemented Standard SQL’s `NATURAL JOIN` syntax, which results in a lot of code to express something quite simple.

Therefore, you could write code such as the second query above but using an actual default value rather than the null value.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle disguised left join:

```
SELECT * FROM A, B
 WHERE a.name = b.name(+)
```

Generic :

```
SELECT a.*, case c.existence WHEN 1 then c.name ELSE NULL END
  FROM A
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT name name, 1 existence FROM B
               UNION ALL
              SELECT a.name name, 0 existence FROM A
               WHERE a.name NOT IN ( SELECT name FROM B )
            ) C
    ON c.name = a.name
```

Comment: **Invaluable**. Especially inside materialized views with `refresh on commit` that perform left-joins (on multiple tables). `left join` keyword or more than one `inner joins` are for some reason not accepted (at least on 12c). Oracle complains with: "The materialized view did not satisfy conditions for refresh at commit time". A way to bypass the restriction is what you provided: `where` with `(+)` for left-joining.

Answer (score 2):

Although left outer joins are the recommended way of writing sql as compared to an alternative but still we can achieve left outer join by using union for the resultset. If we have two table Table1 and Table 2 then we can achieve this by the following -

```
select
       A.Id, 
       A.Col1, 
       A.Col2, 
       A.Col3, 
       B.Id Col4, 
       B.Col1 Col5, 
       B.Col2 Col6, 
       B.Col3 Col7, 
       B.Col4 Col8
from   Table1 A, Table2 B
where  A.Id = B.Id

union all

select
       A.Id, 
       A.Col1, 
       A.Col2, 
       A.Col3, 
       null as Col4, 
       null as Col5, 
       null as Col6, 
       null as Col7, 
       null as Col8
from   Table1 A
where  not exists(select 1 from Table2 B where B.Id = A.Id)
```

This will help achieve the same result but because of the use of Union there could be some performance problems in case the tables are large.