# Left join without using left join with 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, inner-join

I have to get all data from 3 tables with `left join`. I did that with and without using `left join`. But my teacher ask another solution that uses just `inner join`. I just couldn't find the solution please give some advice. Here are the tables:

[image]

And the results should look like this:

[image]

With `left join` solution:

```
SELECT O.*,C.CUST_CODE,C.CUST_NAME,P.PART_CODE,P.PART_NAME 
FROM ORDERS O
LEFT OUTER JOIN PART P ON P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER C ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID
```

Without `left join` solution:

```
SELECT O.*,
(SELECT C.CUST_CODE FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE C.CUST_ID=O.CUST_ID) AS CUST_CODE,
(SELECT C.CUST_NAME FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE C.CUST_ID=O.CUST_ID) AS CUST_NAME,
(SELECT P.PART_CODE FROM PART P WHERE P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID ) AS PART_CODE,
(SELECT P.PART_NAME FROM PART P WHERE P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID ) AS PART_NAME
FROM ORDERS O
```

Comment: That result cannot be done with `inner join`. That's because some of your order contain NULL values for customer or part. Are you 100% sure your teacher said **inner** join ?

Comment: This link should help you solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510481/how-can-i-substitute-a-left-join-in-sql

Comment: @SQLGeorge There are a handful of ways to do this without a `LEFT JOIN`.  This is what I believe the OP is asking.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, but he is specifically asking for inner join.

Comment: @SQLGeorge Yes he wants us to use just inner join

Comment: @VladimirS. There are two tables in that question i have three tables

Comment: @OgünADSAY I gave you a possible solution below.  Essentially, you start off by taking the `INNER JOIN`, and then add back the pieces of the result set which were dropped by taking that inner product of all the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach which uses only `INNER JOIN` and does not use `LEFT JOIN` anywhere.  It begins with your original query using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`, and then adds to that result set the pieces which are missing from taking the inner product of all the tables.

```
SELECT t.* FROM
(
    SELECT O.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_DATE, C.CUST_CODE, C.CUST_NAME, P.PART_CODE, P.PART_NAME 
    FROM ORDERS O
    INNER JOIN PART P
        ON P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C
        ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID
    UNION
    SELECT O.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_DATE, NULL AS CUST_CODE, NULL AS CUST_NAME, P.PART_CODE,
        P.PART_NAME 
    FROM ORDERS O
    INNER JOIN PART P
        ON P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID
    WHERE O.CUST_ID NOT IN (SELECT C.CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMER C)
        OR O.CUST_ID IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT O.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_DATE, C.CUST_CODE, C.CUST_NAME, NULL AS PART_CODE,
        NULL AS PART_NAME 
    FROM ORDERS O
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C
        ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID
    WHERE O.PART_ID NOT IN (SELECT P.PART_ID FROM PART P)
        OR O.PART_ID IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT O.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_DATE, NULL AS CUST_CODE, NULL AS CUST_NAME,
        NULL AS PART_CODE, NULL AS PART_NAME
    FROM ORDERS O
    WHERE (O.CUST_ID NOT IN (SELECT C.CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMER C) AND
           O.PART_ID NOT IN (SELECT P.PART_ID FROM PART P)) OR
           (O.CUST_ID IS NULL AND O.PART_ID IS NULL)
) t
ORDER BY t.ORDER_ID ASC
```

**Follow the link below for a working demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Sir before first UNION is the answer with Left Join itself. I didn't understand what did you did in here? Sorry for bad English.

Comment: @MartinSmith I began with his original query and then modified it to get the answer.  I forgot to remove the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Oh dear...it's time for a Fiddle (growl)

Comment: It returns just 5 rows. It should be 9 rows

Comment: Thank you. 
And I have to mention that he said it can be done with just one SELECT statement. I don't know how :)

Comment: Too bad you didn't mention this sooner, because I won't attempt another answer, as the one I gave you is working fine.

Comment: OMG. I don't know if i should give him this as a result :D
Anyway thank you so much.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for the fiddle, I can now test and understand why my solution is not working :)

Comment: My answer is actually conceptually simple.  It basically does just an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`, and then adds back the pieces which the `INNER JOIN` chopped off.  Try running each `SELECT` in isolation until it is clear what is being done.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did not read the data correctly at first glance. I had not noticed that some customers_id and parts_id in the orders table did not exist in their respective tables... I realized it when I used your fiddle

Comment: No worries...the big challenge here was realizing that the `IS NULL` condition needed to be added to all the post `INNER JOIN` `WHERE` clauses.  Happy to be of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense in "real life", but I understand it's meaningfulness in a SQL course. You have a good teacher.

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM
(   
    SELECT O.*,C.CUST_CODE,C.CUST_NAME,P.PART_CODE,P.PART_NAME 
    FROM ORDERS O
    INNER JOIN PART P ON P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID

    UNION

    SELECT O.*,NULL,NULL,P.PART_CODE,P.PART_NAME 
    FROM ORDERS O
    INNER JOIN PART P ON P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID
    WHERE O.CUST_ID IS NULL

    UNION

    SELECT O.*,C.CUST_CODE,C.CUST_NAME,NULL, NULL
    FROM ORDERS O
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID
    WHERE O.PART_ID IS NULL

    UNION

    SELECT O.*,NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL
    FROM ORDERS O
    WHERE O.PART_ID IS NULL AND O.CUST_ID IS NULL   

)   T

ORDER BY ORDER_ID
```

Comment: Yeah he is the best :)

Comment: I omitted something when I posted it, I edited it 30 seconds  later. Have you tried the latest version? And what is not working ?

Comment: Nope, sorryMsg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: its, not it's -- please ;)

Comment: Sorry still not working. I think we can't write SELECT in FROM,
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Godamn, it should work! Try to remove the main query `SELECT * FROM () ORDER BY` to keep only the 3 nested queries, that's the most important

Comment: I know it seems it should be working but not working I've tried all this.
I did that too removed SELECT * FROM () ORDER BY but it only gives 6 rows 7th,8th and 9th rows are missing

Comment: Thank you for the effort. And I have to mention that he said it can be done with just one SELECT statement. I dont know how :D

Comment: ah I missed that. I still have adapted my query. I'll think to another approach, it's fun. But it's not fun to be downvoted...

Comment: I didn't downvoted. I never downvote anybody :) Just upvoted for the effort  :)

Comment: ok with the fiddle posted by Tim it's easy to understand what's not working with my query: I had not seen that some customers and parts referenced in order table, don't exists in their respective tables.